# I get this error. Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js13

when I use useDispatch in my NextJs Porject, I get this error and everything stops working
Here is the error:
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a

```
import { Provider, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../redux/store';
import axios from "axios";


axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;


const AppComponent = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect (() => {
    dispatch(getLoginInStatus())

  },[dispatch])

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div>
        <ToastContainer />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
    </Provider>
    
  )
} 

export default AppComponent
```

my Provider is properly used, what could be wrong ?

Comment: If you're calling `useDispatch()` in AppComponent, then the provider needs to be *higher* up the component tree than AppComponent. It cannot be inside of AppComponent.

Comment: can you re-write the code to explain what you are talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

The Provider needs to be *higher* up the component tree than where you call `useDispatch`. They cannot be in the same component. So you either need to move the Provider up, or move the `useDispatch` down. For example:

```
const AppComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <InnerComponent {...props} />
    </Provider>
  )
} 

const InnerComponent = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect (() => {
    dispatch(getLoginInStatus())
  },[dispatch])

  return (
    <div>
      <ToastContainer />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </div>
  )
}
```